# Extracting strings from an array of strings given criteria, i.e. a Class's Properties

Tags: c#, arrays, regex, linq

Use Case: I import text files and need to read their contents which consist of 4 lines. With these 4 lines, I parse out string(s) that are not pre-defined, but rather are dynamic.

Here's an example that I gathered from @zx81:

**Input:**

```
on Apr 28, 2014 at 22:00
an Employee John Doe accessed
server - TPCX123
AccessType2 was ReasonType1 - program: Px2x3x, start: No22, 0.0 sec
```

So given the above 4 lines, which I'm thinking of either keeping them with their carriage returns (i.e. as 4 lines) or making it all one string (i.e. just one line), I am going to extract properties and put them into memory via a `Class`'s properties, e.g. `ReportDate`, `ReportTime`, `EmployeeName`, `ServerName`, `AccessType`, `ReasonType`, `ProgramId`, `Start`, `Length`.

**Desired Output:**

```
ReportDate = Apr 28, 2014
ReportTime = 22:00
EmployeeName = John Doe
ServerName = TnCX123
AccessType = AccessType2
ReasonType = ReasonType1
ProgramId = Px2x3x
Start = No22
Length = 0.0 sec
```

This is all I want - all of the items found on the RHS of the equals sign, i.e. certain strings assigned to specific properties found in an `Object` in memory which ultimate respond to a database table's columns. From the above example, the property `EmployeeName` will always be in the same place (between specific strings) and thus will be parsing out its value, e.g. "John Doe". Of course, with every file that I am bringing in, these values will be different, thus the dynamic part of it.

Hope this helps, thanks.

Comment: I understand why you want dog, but why fence?

Comment: Couldn't you just use string.Split(" ")? This will give you an array with all your words.

Comment: What is your criteria for which strings you want?

Comment: Thanks everyone so far that has responded. I have updated my original posting in hopes it answers your questions. Please reference the new section under the "Edit 1" label. Thanks again!

Comment: @user118190 I completely revised my answer to match the new data you supplied. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your data, something like this would output what you want:

**Output:**

```
ReportDate = Apr 28, 2014
ReportTime = 22:00
EmployeeName = John Doe
ServerName = TnCX123
AccessType = AccessType2
ReasonType = ReasonType1
ProgramId = Px2x3x
Start = No22
Length = 0.0 sec
```

**Code:**

```
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
class Program
{

    static void Main()
    {
    string s1 = @"on Apr 28, 2014 at 22:00
an Employee John Doe accessed
server - TPCX123
AccessType2 was ReasonType1 - program: Px2x3x, start: No22, 0.0 sec";

    try
    {
    var myRegex = new Regex(@"(?s)^on\s+([\w, ]+?) at (\d{2}:\d{2}).*?Employee ([\w ]+) accessed.*?server - (\w+).*?(\w+) was (\w+) - program: (\w+), start: (\w+), (\d+\.\d+ \w+)");
    string date = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[1].Value;
    string time = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[2].Value;
    string name = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[3].Value;
    string server = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[4].Value;
    string access = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[5].Value;
    string reason = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[6].Value;
    string prog = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[7].Value;
    string start = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[8].Value;
    string length = myRegex.Match(s1).Groups[9].Value;
    Console.WriteLine("ReportDate = " + date);
    Console.WriteLine("ReportTime = " + time);
    Console.WriteLine("EmployeeName = " + name);
    Console.WriteLine("ServerName = " + server);
    Console.WriteLine("AccessType = " + access);
    Console.WriteLine("ReasonType = " + reason);
    Console.WriteLine("ProgramId = " + prog);
    Console.WriteLine("Start = " + start);
    Console.WriteLine("Length = " + length);
    }
    catch (ArgumentException ex)
    {
    // We have a syntax error
    }

    Console.WriteLine("\nPress Any Key to Exit.");
    Console.ReadKey();
    } // END Main
} // END Program
```

**Tweaking it**

However, to tweak it you are going to have to brush up your regex.

To start you off, here is a token-by-token explanation of the regex in the code. Then I recommend you visit the [FAQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22937618/reference-what-does-this-regex-mean/22944075#22944075), [RexEgg](http://www.rexegg.com) and other sites mentioned in the FAQ.

```
@"
(?                 # Use these options for the whole regular expression
   s                  # Dot matches line breaks
)
^                  # Assert position at the beginning of the string
on                 # Match the character string “on” literally (case sensitive)
\s                 # Match a single character that is a “whitespace character” (any Unicode separator, tab, line feed, carriage return, vertical tab, form feed, next line)
   +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 1
   [\w,\ ]            # Match a single character present in the list below
                         # A “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
                         # A single character from the list “, ”
      +?                 # Between one and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
)
\ at\              # Match the character string “ at ” literally (case sensitive)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 2
   \d                 # Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script)
      {2}                # Exactly 2 times
   :                  # Match the character “:” literally
   \d                 # Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script)
      {2}                # Exactly 2 times
)
.                  # Match any single character
   *?                 # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
Employee\          # Match the character string “Employee ” literally (case sensitive)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 3
   [\w\ ]             # Match a single character present in the list below
                         # A “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
                         # The literal character “ ”
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\ accessed         # Match the character string “ accessed” literally (case sensitive)
.                  # Match any single character
   *?                 # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
server\ -\         # Match the character string “server - ” literally (case sensitive)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 4
   \w                 # Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
.                  # Match any single character
   *?                 # Between zero and unlimited times, as few times as possible, expanding as needed (lazy)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 5
   \w                 # Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\ was\             # Match the character string “ was ” literally (case sensitive)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 6
   \w                 # Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
\ -\ program:\     # Match the character string “ - program: ” literally (case sensitive)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 7
   \w                 # Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
,\ start:\         # Match the character string “, start: ” literally (case sensitive)
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 8
   \w                 # Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
,\                 # Match the character string “, ” literally
(                  # Match the regex below and capture its match into backreference number 9
   \d                 # Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \.                 # Match the character “.” literally
   \d                 # Match a single character that is a “digit” (0–9 in any Unicode script)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
   \                  # Match the character “ ” literally
   \w                 # Match a single character that is a “word character” (Unicode; any letter or ideograph, digit, connector punctuation)
      +                  # Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed (greedy)
)
"
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks @zx81 for the VERY helpful explanation in understanding the solution and the concepts behind them!

Comment: @user118190 Hey you're welcome, it was a pleasure, glad to hear that it works. Thanks for your kind feedback. :) By the way you should know that I did not write the token-by-token explanation by hand: I asked regexbuddy to generate it [(trial here)](http://yu8.us/rbdemo). If you're going to be doing what it seems like you're about to be doing, that could be a worthwhile tool.